# Qualtrics: Slider bar with two sliders knobs to indicate intervals

Tags: qualtrics

I am looking for a way to create a slider with two knobs on a combined range, such that people can indicate an interval by setting the upper and lower limit. I would hope for it to look like this:

[image]

It would be great if one slider could be the "upper" and one the "lower" limit; i.e., for both not to be able to cross over.

In addition, I would like to display a value computed based on the values of both sliders. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really possible without some HEAVY custom coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a Qualtrics survey file with the modified slider [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rl4z0q1pplaycf5/MLI_Sliders.qsf?dl=0).

Note that when importing the slider into an existing survey, you need to add some custom CSS. This can be found in two places:

Look and Feel -> General -> Header
Look and Feel -> Style -> Custom CSS